# Laplace transform of $\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}\frac {\partial ^2 u}{\partial x_i^2 \partial x_j^2}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, elliptic-operators

It's said that if I have the elliptic partial differential equations: $\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}\frac {\partial ^2 u}{\partial x_i^2 \partial x_j^2}$, it's transferable to $\nabla ^2 = \frac {\partial ^2}{\partial x_i ^2}$ by the linear Laplace transform iff the matrix of this transformation $A$ is positive semi-definitive, but why the positive semi-definiteness?

I was trying to find some proof but it was too hard for me, I just want to understand it.

Comment: Taking the Laplace transform it becomes $\hat{u}({\bf s}) \sum s_ia_{ij}s_j = \hat{u}({\bf s}) {\bf s}^T A {\bf s} = \ldots$ (some function of $s$). You want to perform a linear change of variables ${\bf s}\to {\bf s'}$ such that ${\bf s}^T A {\bf s} = \|{\bf s'}\|^2$. Not possible if the left hand side can be negative.

Comment: Thank you, but why that norm?

Comment: Because the Laplace transform of $\nabla'^2u$ is $\|{\bf s'}\|^2\hat{u}({\bf s'}) + \cdots$. It would be good if you can clarify what you mean by "transferable to $\nabla^2$" so it's sure we are talking about the same thing. The way I read the statement originally was that there is a linear change of variables that makes the differential operator diagonal, but maybe that's not what you are asking about?